# How to order a controller by a virtual attribute that takes a param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to order a "Post" index by the last activity date by the current_user or the current_user's friends. The post can be created or reposted (a different model).

Using my current approach, I get "undefined method `last_friend_update' for #Class:0x000000023a0e38"

**Models**
Post Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reposts
  has_many :resposters, :through => :resposts, :source => :user

  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = user.friend_ids
    repost_ids = user.reposts.map(&:post_id)
    friend_reposts_ids = user.friend_reposts.map(&:post_id)
    comment_ids = user.comments.map(&:post_id)
    friend_comment_ids = user.friend_comments.map(&:post_id)
    where(['user_id IN (:followed_user_ids) OR user_id = :user_id 
            OR id IN (:repost_ids) OR id IN (:friend_reposts_ids)
            OR id IN (:comment_ids) OR id IN (:friend_comment_ids)',
      {followed_user_ids: followed_user_ids, user_id: user, 
       repost_ids: repost_ids, friend_reposts_ids: friend_reposts_ids,
       comment_ids: comment_ids, friend_comment_ids: friend_comment_ids}])
  end

def self.last_friend_update(user)
    post_date = :created_at.to_s
    user_repost_date = user.reposts.where(['post_id = :post_id',{post_id: :id}]).map(&:created_at).max.to_s
    friends_repost_date = user.friend_reposts.where(['post_id = :post_id',{post_id: :id}]).map(&:created_at).max.to_s
    user_comment_date = user.comments.where(['post_id = :post_id',{post_id: :id}]).map(&:created_at).max.to_s
    friend_comment_date = user.friend_comments.where(['post_id = :post_id',{post_id: :id}]).map(&:created_at).max.to_s
    most_recent_date = [post_date, user_repost_date, user_comment_date, friend_comment_date].max.to_s
  end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :reposts
  has_many :reposted_posts, :through => :reposts, :source => :post
  has_many :friend_posts, :through => :friendships, :source => :posts
  has_many :friend_reposts, :through => :friendships, :source => :reposts
end
```

Friendship Model:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :posts, :foreign_key => "user_id", :primary_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :reposts, :foreign_key => "user_id", :primary_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :comments, :foreign_key => "user_id", :primary_key => "friend_id"
end
```

**Posts Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      @posts = Post.from_users_followed_by(current_user).sort_by("#{Post.last_friend_update(current_user)}")
    else
      @all_posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc")
    end
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :url, :summary, :title, :last_friend_udpate)
  end
end
```

## Update

Post Model

```
  def last_friend_update(user)
    # setting some initial variables here, so they won't error if null later
    post_date = self.created_at.to_datetime
    user_repost_date = "01-01-1960".to_datetime
    friends_repost_date = "01-01-1960".to_datetime
    user_comment_date = "01-01-1960".to_datetime
    friend_comment_date = "01-01-1960".to_datetime
    # Getting most recent dates for the current_user and their firends on the post
    user_repost_maxdate = user.reposts.where(['post_id = :post_id',{post_id: self.id}]).map(&:created_at).max
    friends_repost_maxdate = user.friend_reposts.where(['post_id = :post_id',{post_id: self.id}]).map(&:created_at).max
    user_comment_maxdate = user.comments.where(['post_id = :post_id',{post_id: self.id}]).map(&:created_at).max
    friend_comment_maxdate = user.friend_comments.where(['post_id = :post_id',{post_id: self.id}]).map(&:created_at).max
    # If there are recent dates for activities, set the variables as such
    unless user_repost_maxdate.nil?
      user_repost_date = user_repost_maxdate.to_datetime
    end
    unless friends_repost_maxdate.nil?
      friends_repost_date = friends_repost_maxdate.to_datetime
    end
    unless user_comment_maxdate.nil?
      user_comment_date = user_comment_maxdate.to_datetime
    end
    unless friend_comment_maxdate.nil?
      friend_comment_date = friend_comment_maxdate.to_datetime
    end
    # get the max of the activity date_times.
    [post_date.to_datetime, user_repost_date.to_datetime, friends_repost_date, user_comment_date.to_datetime, friend_comment_date.to_datetime].max
  end
```

Post Controller section:

```
# sort_by lets me use the block format, while order_by did not.
# I reverse at the end to have the most recent post at the top.
@posts = Post.from_users_followed_by(current_user).sort_by{ |post| post.last_friend_update(current_user) }.reverse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model you've got `last_friend_udpate`, in the post params you have `last_friend_udpate`, but in the index you have `last_friend_update`

Comment: Good catch! But I'm still getting the same error. Weird right?

Comment: You're trying to call last_friend_update in your index action as if it were a class method. You probably wanted to define it as a class method like self.last_friend_update. Either that or you should be using the block form of sort_by like sort_by { |post| post.last_friend_update(user).to_s }

Comment: Good call, I've fixed that and a few other issues in the model. Now I am getting "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" in the controller.

Comment: Post updated code, and what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Nevermind, I changed it from "sort_by" to "order", and it works!  Thanks for your help here!

Comment: I ended going with the block form ultimatly. The final relevant posts controller and model sections are above for anyone interested. I'm sure it could be done prettier, but it works :)